# Selenium pagefacotry not working searchcontext error

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run with pagefactory for web elements of login function.

I am getting error after running with testng.

And it shows that searchcontext error. I tried to run with xpath, but still same error.

Any help woul d be appreciated.

```
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void bfTest() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String url = "https://www.example.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.get(url);
        
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
    }
    
    public void test_case_01 () {
        login = new Login(driver);
        
        login.enter_username("name");
        login.enter_password("password");
        login.click_login();
        
        List<WebElement> list_products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item']"));
        int number_products = list_products.size();
        System.out.println("Verifying login is the number of products: " + number_products);
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(number_products, 6);
    }

public class Login {
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(xpath="user-name")
    private WebElement name;
    @FindBy(name="password")
    private WebElement pwd;
    @FindBy(name="login-button")
    public WebElement login;
    public Login (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void enter_username(String username) {
        
        name.sendKeys(username);
        
    }
```

I am getting this error after failing to pass the code above. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Object)'
    at com.eCommerce.test.Login.<init>(Login.java:26)
    at com.eCommerce.test.Main.test_case_01(Main.java:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Where are your imports?

Comment: well. I forgot to add above, but they are import already in login class.import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;